# validation for two select box using array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array 'a' which is like this

```
            var a = new Array();
             a[key] =a[value];
             a['mpp']='mpp';
             a['pdf']='pdf';
             a['Excel']='xls';
             a['word']='doc';
             a['ppt']='ppt';
             a['html']='html';
```

I have two select box one is docFormat which contains a[key] and another is extension which contains a[value], on submit I have to validate the two select box from this array , can you please suggest some help?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the validation passes or fails?

Comment: i have to compare both select box option value and validate whether for example if 1 select box value is excel it should match with another select box value as xls , if both the condition satisfies then only , i have to submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

```
function validate(){
    var key = $("#select-key").val(),
        val = $("#select-value").val();
    return key in a && a[key] == val;
}
```

Assuming `a` is your array and your select boxes have the IDs `select-key` and `select-value` respectively.
Hope this helps.